# Deficiency indices for differential operator on half-line

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory

1) What is the domain of the adjoint $A^\ast$ of the differential operator
$Af = i \frac{d}{dx}$ with $D(A) = \mathcal C^\infty_c (0,\infty)$?

2) I want to compute the deficiency indices of $A$. By definition we have
$d_+(A) = \dim \ker (A^\ast - i I) = \dim \ker (T^\ast - \lambda I)$ for $Im \lambda > 0 $ and
$d_-(A) = \dim \ker (A^\ast + i I) = \dim \ker (T^\ast - \lambda I)$ for $Im \lambda < 0$.
Now, the exponentials $e^{i \lambda x}$ are the possible candidates for eigenfunctions of $A^\ast$ and they only are square-integrable if $Im \lambda > 0$, so i would say $d_+(A) = 1$ while $D_-(A) = 0$ and hence the operator has no self-adjoint extension. Is this correct?

Comment: The operator $A$ in question is important in QM – it is the momentum on a halfline. See [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/446530/42966) on the Physics StackExchange.